# Checking a "password" string for space and returning true if found: C++

Tags: c++, string, vector

I am new to C++ and am working on a basic username and passsword program in C++ that uses vectors. Currently I am stuck on a function that checks a password string for a space and returns true if this happens. I was trying to implement isspace() but could not figure out if it was checking my string "password" or not. Thank you in advance for taking the time to review and help in any way. I apologize in advance if I am lacking any key information.

```
    bool checkSpaces (string password) {
        for (int i = 0; i < password.length(); i++) {
            if (isspace(i)) {
                return true;
            } else {
                return false;
        }
    }
```

Comment: are you serious? you're checking if the loop index is a space character? You should really check the code you write before posting here...

Comment: `return (password.find_first_of(' ') != std::string::npos);`

Comment: @osnapitzkindle That kind of defeats the purpose of posting and asking for help. Obviously I am having difficulties and asking for advice. If I understood it and "checked" my code before posting, I wouldn't need to post...

Comment: ok, but this is a really basic problem. obviously it's not the i to be checked, but the character at index i on the string, and as the answerer says, adding a return false like that would just return false at the first loop step. Move that instruction after the loop.

Comment: Are basic problems not allowed here? I apologize if this forum cannot be used for such questions, but I would rather ask and have my simple mistakes and lack of understanding pointed out than go on not knowing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By the way, I changed your `isspace()` to use the password string and not the loop index.  This is probably a typo.

Because you have the `else` clause, the loop executes only once, either the first character is a space and it returns true, **else** it returns false.

Try with pen and paper.

```
   bool checkSpaces (string password) {
        for (int i = 0; i < password.length(); i++) {
            if (isspace(password[i])) {
                return true;
            }
/* --> */   else {
                return false;
        }
    }
```

The content of the loop says that if the character is not a space, return false.  So when it hits a non-space character, it returns, regardless of how many characters have been examined.

Remove the else statement:

```
   bool checkSpaces (string password) {
        for (int i = 0; i < password.length(); i++) {
            if (isspace(password[i])) {
                return true;
            }
        }
        // If the for loop terminates, and gets here,
        // there were no spaces.
        return false;
    }
```

Comment: Thank you for explaining it kindly and not taking my post as a joke. In my head I was thinking it wouldn't execute properly with the false else return and am still learning.

Comment: If the answer is helpful, please click on the check mark.

Comment: Most helpful, checked!